# Change in rotational kinetic energy? where it comes from?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

Consider a rotating object, If its moment of inertia decreases its angular velocity increases, in order to conserve angular momentum. But what happens to rotational kinetic energy? Why it changes, we are not applying any force/ torque. Neglect all types of frictions, and take an ideal case.

Comment: You say you are not applying any force, but how does the moment of inertia change? There are forces involved there.

Comment: what if we say the rotating body shrinks due to change in temperature?

Comment: if forces are involved in changing moment of inertia, why they don't affect conservation of angular momentum?
or am i missing some basic concept?

Comment: Hi Hamza and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: A possible example of this is an accretion disk.

Comment: If there is a decrease in temperature there is a source of energy for the increase in kinetic energy.  Regarding conservation ideas, don't assume that conservation in a system means constancy. For example, work on a system changes the total energy of the system, but energy is still conserved because it is neither created nor destroyed. Work simply transfers energy in or out of the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bill N indicated, there does have to be a force in order to rearrange the particles in the system so that the moment of inertia changes. This means that work is being done on the system (or extracted from the system), so that the total energy can change.

You also suggested that a rotating body might change size due to temperature changes, but this answers your own question: changing the temperature would require a change in the energy of the system.

Finally, you asked how a force could change the moment of inertia without affecting the angular momentum. If the force is directed radially, it does not create a torque on the system so there would be no change in angular momentum.

Comment: And there's nothing wrong with changing the angular momentum of a system. Angular momentum is still a conserved quantity. That doesn't equate with being a constant inside the system. There can be external torque which adds or removes angular momentum.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the classic example:  a spinning figure skater who pulls in his arms and increases his rate of spin.

We define the system as the body of the skater.  Any forces acting from outside this system is an ***external*** force and torques;  any force acting between parts of the skater are ***internal*** forces and torques.  **Defining "the system" explicitly is the essential starting point for any calculation involving conservation of momentum, angular or linear.**

Firstly, there are no external torques.  We are neglecting air friction, and the friction of the ice on the skate blades.

Therefore, ***the angular momentum of the skater remains constant***.

Secondly, as the skater pulls his arms and legs closer to his body (and the vertical axis of rotation), the total moment of inertia of the skater decreases.
In combination with the constant AM above, this means that the ***angular velocity of the skater increases***.

The relationship is a linear one;$$AM = MI \times \omega$$S, if the MI is cut in half, the angular velocity will double.

Finally, consider the rotational kinetic energy: $$KE_{Rot} =\frac 12MI \times \omega ^2$$

In the case above, with the MI cut in half, and the angular velocity doubled, the rotational kinetic energy is doubled.

The skater adds this kinetic energy to the system.  He must exert an inward force to pull his arms inward.  He is exerting a force through a distance; he is doing work.  The work he does pulling in his arms can be shown to be equal to the increase in rotational kinetic energy.

Comment: One thing to note here is that the skater contains a store of non-mechanical (chemical) energy which can be converted to mechanical energy.  In most elementary mechanics problems, the system does not have a non-mechanical store of energy, so we are inclined to forget to include any such stores.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a simple system with a mass $m$ at a distance $r$ from the axis of rotation, rotating at angular velocity $\omega$. The centripetal force required is of course

$$F = m \omega^2 r$$

Putting the angular momentum $L = I\omega = m r^2 \omega$, we can rewrite the force as

$$F = \frac{L^2}{m r^3}$$

Now we know that $L$ is constant: if we want to move from $r=r_0$ to $r=r_1$, we do have to apply a variable force, and it's easy to compute the work done:

$$E = \int F\cdot dr = \int \frac{L^2 dr}{r^3} = \frac{ L^2}{2}\left(\frac{1}{r_0^2}-\frac{1}{r_1^2}\right)$$

Of course, the energy associated with the rotation at a particular radius can also be described in terms of the angular velocity and the radius - and you can see immediately that the change in kinetic energy is equal to the work done to pull in the weight.

Of course while this analysis was done for a single point mass, it's easy to see how you could integrate over a distribution of point masses - showing that the same analysis is valid for any shape.